# color Hex to imagefilledrectangle

Tags: php, image

I am having problems with filling in the correct color:

```
$bgColor = '9EA5FF';
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 11, 214,'0x' . $bgColor);
```

**OR**

```
$bgColor = '0x9EA5FF';
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 11, 214,$bgColor);
```

Seems that the code(s) above does not fill in the square as it should (its just black) but this code:

```
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 11, 214,'0x9EA5FF');
```

Does.

What am i doing incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function html2rgb($color)
 {
   if ($color[0] == '#')
       $color = substr($color, 1);

   if (strlen($color) == 6)
       list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0].$color[1],
                             $color[2].$color[3],
                             $color[4].$color[5]);
   elseif (strlen($color) == 3)
       list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0].$color[0], $color[1].$color[1], $color[2].$color[2]);
   else
       return false;

   $r = hexdec($r); $g = hexdec($g); $b = hexdec($b);

   return array($r, $g, $b);
}


$theRGB = html2rgb($bgColor);
$background = imagecolorallocate($im, $theRGB[0], $theRGB[1], $theRGB[2]);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 11, 214,$background);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your $bgColor variable with the imagecolorallocate() function using the RGB triplet for your desired color. imagecolorallocate() is designed to return a color identifier to be passed to imagefilledrectangle().

According to the documentation for GD, "imagecolorallocate() must be called to create each color that is to be used in the image represented by image."

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Comment: You can replace the line that reads $bgColor = '9EA5FF'; with this: $bgColor = imagecolorallocate($im , 168, 155, 255);